# Не работает цикл js

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести строку "0_10_1_9_2_8_3_7_4_6_5_5_6_4_7_3_8_2_9_1_10_0_". Внешний цикл выводит числа на четных позициях (от 0 до 10) внутренний цикл - числа на нечетных позициях (от 10 до 0).Пытался сделать(не правильно):

```js
let j = 0;
while (j < 2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    document.write(i + "_");
  };
  for (let k = 11; k > 1; k--) {
    document.write(k + "_");
  };
  document.write('<br>');
  j++
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в цикле `for` можно итерировать несколько переменных

```js
for(let i=0,j=10;i <=10 && j >=0;i++,j--){
  document.write(`${i}_${j}_`);
}
```

через `while`:

```js
let i = 0,
  j = 10;

while (i <= 10 && j >= 0) {
  document.write(`${i}_${j}_`);
  i++;
  j--;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, был рад усвоить новый материал с твоей помощью!АУФИЛГУД